# Cannot "break" loop in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, break

### Problem

I'm trying to loop through an array of Elements in VueJS and return the first one that does not have a given class. However, whenever I use [Break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break), Vue refuses to compile

### Code

```
let section = null;

this.sectionList.forEach(s => {
    if(!s.classList.contains('complete')){
       section = s;
       break;
    }
});

return section;
```

### The Error

> app.js:73816 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   C:/Users/Lewis/homestead/projects/bookitzone/resources/js/frontend/components/sections/form-section.vue:
>   Unsyntactic break (72:20)

[image]

Comment: Fair enough. I though this was Vue related. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Vue is just a javascript framework, so the same things apply (at least in this case) as with javascript...

Comment: you should use `return` instead of `break`. and btw this is just js its not related to vuejs

Comment: let section = null;

this.sectionList.forEach(s => {
    if(!s.classList.contains('complete')){
       section = s;
       return true
    }
});

return section;